# Folder not displaying Content Type fields

Tags: sharepoint, directory, content-type, field

I have created a folder template on site collection level which holds a number of fields.
After creating a new team site under that site collection, I went on creating a new document library which holds four folders build from that content type.

When I edit the properties of the folder the fields are displayed correctly.

The problem is that after saving that site as site template I went on to create a new site by that template, and on this site when I try to edit the folder properties the fields are not showin!

This is very strange. I tried to delete and create the folder template again, but that didn't fix it.

This is happening on  a production computer, I've done this countless times before on my station and it worked fine.

Does anyone know how I can fix this?

Comment: I have the same problem, but with list template. When I create a list form the list template (which contains folders), the fields are broken (so ct["ContentType"] is not working). The properties are still ok (so ct.ContentType.Name is working). But if you want to use caml query to filter item by content type, it will search in the fields not in the properties, so it will return nothing... 

Did you manage to solve this somehow?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed that with a workaround. I saved my documents libraries and lists as templates, then I created the documents libraries and lists from those templates in the production. That works fine...

Have you ever fixed that in another solution?